# Run a javascript when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have a button underneath a WebView. When I click on it I want a javascript of run on the WebView.

This doesn't work:

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
            String script = "javascript:document.getElementById('lnkNxtPg').click()";
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.nextPg:
                webView.loadUrl(script);
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }       
        }
```

but this works:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.nextPg:
            webView.loadUrl("www.google.com");
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }       
    }
```

How can I make the first example work?

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand how [to Call JavaScript Function from Android and handling result](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/10/calling-javascript-function-from.html)